# How to custom driver in wince 6.0?

Tags: windows-ce

i have changed the registry settings as per the msdn
but when i connect to pc then it shows usb not recongnized/

settings i used is given below

> ;================================================================================= [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\USB\FunctionDrivers\CompositeFN]
>     "Attributes"=multi_sz:"0x80"
>     "bcdDevice" =dword:0
>     "DefaultPrefix"="CompositeFn_"
>     "ManufacturerString"="Composite USB"
>     "MaxPacketSize"=dword:40
>     "PowerConsumption"=multi_sz:"0x00"
>     "ProductString"="CompositDriver"
>     "SerialString"="0x22"
>     "ProductID"=dword:233a
>     "VendorID"=dword:0001
>     "DefaultString"="e-con Composite
>   Driver"
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\USB\FunctionDrivers\Serial_Class]
>
> "CompositeFn_DefaultString"="
>   ActiveSync"
>   "CompositeFn_FunctionClass"=dword:0a
>   "CompositeFn_FunctionDescription"="USB
>   ActiveSync"
>   "CompositeFn_FunctionProtocol"=dword:ff
>   "CompositeFn_FunctionSubclass"=dword:00
>   ;"CompositeFN_DisableIAD"=dword:1
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\USB\FunctionDrivers\Mass_Storage_Class]
>
> "CompositeFn_DefaultString"="ASI
>   DataMyte Mass Storage"
>   "CompositeFn_FunctionClass"=dword:08
>   "CompositeFn_FunctionDescription"="USB
>   MassStorage"
>   "CompositeFn_FunctionProtocol"=dword:ff
>   "CompositeFn_FunctionSubclass"=dword:00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\USB\FunctionDrivers\CompositeFN]
>   "ClientDriverList"=multi_sz:"Mass_Storage_Class","Serial_Class"
>       [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\USB\FunctionDrivers]
>   "DefaultClientDriver"="CompositeFN"

Answer (score 0):

Is the actual driver in the OS image?  What comes out the debug port when you plug in the device?  Connecting with Platform Builder via KITL would be a good next step as you could step through the entire driver initialization code path.

Comment: thnaks for reply yes driver is in platform.i don't know how to use kitl:( please give your suggestion

Comment: Using KITL is way beyond the scope of an SO answer.  There are entire books on using Platform Builder. How about the debug port?  What do you see there?